# How to get the main object of a firebase database?

Tags: javascript, firebase

Here's a quite simple question but I have not been able to find an answer anywhere about this, so hopefully I can get the answer here.

I want to iterate through the keys in my database using:

```
for (var key in X) {
    //X is the main object I need
}
```

However, in order to do this I need the actual object of the database, not the reference to the database. Because when I iterate over the reference I get a lot of nonsense properties. So how do I get the object containing all the keys that I add personally? Hopefully my question makes sense.

Comment: Ref.on('value', function(snapshot) { value = snapshot.val() })

Comment: "I have not been able to find an answer anywhere about this": https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html

Comment: I'm sure that explains it but it's very hard to fully understand it if you're fairly novice. I need better explanations than what they provide in their API guide in order to understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done this way:

```
var value;
myDataRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
   value = snapshot.val();
})
```